# What groups contain a value - more elegant code?

Tags: r

I'm trying to find a more elegant way to extract all rows of a data frame if one member of a group contains a specific value. For example:

```
id <- c(1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5,5)
cat <- c("A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "B", "C", "D", "A", "E")
mydf <- data.frame(id, cat)

id cat
1   A
1   B
2   A
2   B
2   C
3   B
4   C
4   D
5   A
5   E
```

I'd like to create a new data frame with *all* rows from ids that contain C, in this case *all* rows from id 2 and id 4, not just those rows that contain C.

I've done it this way, but I'm thinking there must be a more elegant way to do it without creating 2 extra columns:

```
mydf$isC <- ifelse(cat=="C", TRUE, FALSE) 
library(dplyr)
newdf <- mydf %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(
   hasC = ifelse(any(isC), TRUE, FALSE)
  ) %>%
  filter(hasC)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
mydf%>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    filter( any(cat=='C'))
#   id cat
#1  2   A
#2  2   B
#3  2   C
#4  4   C
#5  4   D
```

Or if you need to remove the rows with 'C' among the groups selected, use `& cat!= 'C'`

```
mydf%>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   filter( any(cat=='C')& cat!='C')
#  id cat
#1  2   A
#2  2   B
#3  4   D
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)[,.SD[any(cat=='C') & cat!='C'] , id]
#   id cat
#1:  2   A
#2:  2   B
#3:  4   D
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
subset(mydf, id %in% id[cat=="C"])
##   id cat
## 3  2   A
## 4  2   B
## 5  2   C
## 7  4   C
## 8  4   D
```

Or for non-interactive use,

```
mydf[mydf$id %in% mydf$id[mydf$cat == "C"],]
```